# How would I change IPN auto response to SMTP

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

```
 $headers = "From: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
          $headers .= "Reply-To: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
          $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

          $sql9=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks_accounts` WHERE `cpid`='".$row1['cpid']."'");
          $row9=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql9);
          $to2      = $row9['email'];
          $subject2 = "New Airport Parking Booking Confirmation";
          $message2 .= "<p>Your car park has received a new booking through SpeedyPark.</p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Booking ID: <b>".$bid."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Name: <b>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['sname']."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Drop Off Dates: <b>".date('d/m/Y', $row1['sdate'])." - ".$row1['stime']."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Pick Up Dates: <b>".date('d/m/Y', $row1['edate'])." - ".$row1['etime']."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Outbound Flight: <b>Terminal ".$row8['terminalout']." - Flight ".$row8['flightout']."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Return Flight: <b>Terminal ".$row8['terminalin']." - Flight ".$row8['flightin']."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Price: <b>".$row1['price']."</b></p>";
          $message2 .= "<p>Vehicle: <b>".$row4['reg']." - ".$row4['make']." ".$row4['model']." - ".$row4['colour']."</b></p>";
          if ($row1['cpeid'] == "") {
          } else {
            $message2 .= "<h3>Extras</h3>";
            $extralist = explode(', ', $row1['cpeid']);
            foreach($extralist as $value) //loop over values
            { 
            $sql17 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `carparks_extras` WHERE `id`='".$value."'");
            $row17 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql7);
              $message2 .= $row17['name']."<br/>";
            }
          }
          $headers2 = "From: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
          $headers2 .= "Reply-To: reservation@speedypark.co.uk \r\n";
          $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
          mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);
          $sql6 = "UPDATE `bookings` SET `status`='confirmed' WHERE `id`='".$bid."'";
          $results1 = mysql_query($sql6);
```

I have an ipn.php which won't work because the server is blacklisted and maybe another error with in the code. Would it be possible to change it to send through smtp settings? It loads the strings through mysql.

Comment: Yes, replace `mail` function with phpmailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp

Comment: Or use a transactional email service like mandril (free)

Comment: You need to [stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) because they've been removed from PHP.

Comment: Hi steve would it be easy to implement mandril with IPN or have i got the process mixed up and mandril is a process itself

Comment: Hello Mark, the above code is just a regular php script. The fact it gets called by paypal servers with IPN data is incidental - the script can do anything you like, including calling the madrill api to send an email

Comment: Steve, I'm not the wisest of people like some of the others on here. Would it be possible we speak over email or through direct message on here about a solution? marksww1